# Alarm intent entering rapid infinite loop

Tags: android

I'm trying to code a block of code that has to wake up a few times a day and notify a server. I'm trying to use an alarm intent and a broadcast receiver but the receiver is being rapidly triggered infinitely and I can't seem to stop this.

All of my code sits in one file. The process flow is simple.
Wake up on boot, check if we should communicate, attempt to communicate else set up one of two waiting conditions, activate alarm.
Wake up on alarm, attempt to communicate, re-activate alarm if necessary, otherwise kill it.

When I build and deploy this apk on my device the following process flow happens: 
reboot
receiver receives boot intent just fine
alarm gets scheduled
alarm intent gets triggered after 80 seconds as intended
then after the next 80 seconds, 
then log-cat shows the broadcast receiver being triggered very rapidly.
 Several times a second as if its being spammed.

I am completely baffled at why its behaving like this

```
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
/**
 * Receive a signal, in our case, the device has booted up
 * @param context The Context in which the receiver is running.
 * @param intent  The Intent being received.
 */
@SuppressLint("UnsafeProtectedBroadcastReceiver")
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("autostart", "broadcast received");
    if(intent.getAction()==null)return;
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, autostart.class);
    alarmIntent.setAction("device.activation.alarm");
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);//cancel flag seems to be ignored
    cancel(context);//cancel command seems to be ignored
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
        // Set the alarm here.
        Log.d("autostart","We have booted");
        RegisterActivation registerActivation = new RegisterActivation(context);
        if(registerActivation.AlreadyActivated())
            return;//no need
        if(registerActivation.ActivationPending()){
            //perform regular activation
            return;
        }
        if(registerActivation.canComplete()){
            boolean success = registerActivation.sendActivation();//talk to server
            if(success) {
                registerActivation.markCompleted();
                cancel(context);
            }
            else {
                registerActivation.markFileWaiting();
                startPending(context);
            }
            return;
        }
        if(registerActivation.shouldWait()){//if can complete fails, then shouldWait will immediately return true
            Log.d("autostart", "waiting");
            registerActivation.markFileSimWait();
            startWait(context);
            return;
        }
    }
    if(intent.getAction().equals("device.activation.alarm")){
        Log.d("autostart","alarm triggered");
        cancel(context);
        RegisterActivation registerActivation = new RegisterActivation(context);
        if(registerActivation.AlreadyActivated()){//for now always false
            cancel(context);
            return;
        }
        if(registerActivation.ActivationPending()){//for now always false
            //same as before
            return;
        }
        if(registerActivation.canComplete()){//glitch happens here
            if(registerActivation.sendActivation()){
                registerActivation.markCompleted();
                cancel(context);
            }else{
                registerActivation.markFileWaiting();
                startPending(context);//this immediatly triggers the broadcast recieve
            }
            return;
        }
        if(registerActivation.shouldWait()){
            registerActivation.markFileSimWait();
            startWait(context);
        }
    }
}

public void startPending(Context context) {
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    int interval = 80000;//will later become 4 hours
    manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,interval,pendingIntent);
    Log.d("autostart", "alarm activated");
}

public void startWait(Context context) {//same function but different time interval
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    int interval = 90000;// will later become 12 hours
    manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, interval, pendingIntent);
}

public void cancel(Context context) {
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: The times you're passing to `AlarmManager#set()` are _waaay_ in the past, so the alarms will fire pretty much immediately. `RTC*` alarms are based on "wall clock" time, which, right now, is greater than 1527019821000ms (UTC). You want to pass an actual time there, not a delay interval; e.g., `System.currentTimeMillis() + interval`. I would also mention that `set()` hasn't been exact since KitKat, so if that's a concern, you'll need to use an appropriate method for the given API level.

Comment: That's worked, Thanks Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you to Mike M.
https://stackoverflow.com/users/2850651/mike-m

I'd mark your comment as the answer but you only commented

I went from

```
manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,interval,pendingIntent);
```

to:

```
manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+interval, interval, pendingIntent);
```

I had to add the interval to the intervalMillis paramater.
And as tested, the manager.set(...) function is really not responding all too well to what I want it to do so I just have to trigger a cancel at the start.

Thanks again Mike :)